# Where is a list of SharePoint 2010 wiki improvements?

Tags: sharepoint, wiki

Do you know where there is a list of SharePoint 2010 wiki improvements?

I'm really hoping they added something equivalent to wikipedia categories -- so we can throw a category marker such as [Category:TODO] into a page, and have it automagically show up on a list of todo items as long as that category is present.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a new feature that allows you to do that. It is not just wiki feature but a general one named [Managed Metadata](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2009/12/managed-metadata-in-sharepoint-2010-key.html). In essence allows you to tag your content with unlimited corporate and on-demand tags.

You can create such a column for Wiki library and then tag your pages with such a tag.

The key new features for Wikis in 2010 are (just a few I can remember now):

- Every page is a wiki now
- With the new fluent UI it is much easier to modify and create wiki pages